# How to Count number of Subsites in a SharePoint Site using CSOM in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, office365, csom

I want to count number of subsites, groups, list available in a single Site in sharepoint and display it in a List. How to do it in .NET using CSOM. I've tried like this but this is not working.

```
 Tenant tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
                //SiteProperties sites = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("https://developer19.sharepoint.com/sites/codesite",true);
                var sites = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
                sites.Context.Load(sites);
                sites.Context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach( var siteProp in sites)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Site Collection '{0}' has '{1}' subwebs", siteProp.Url, siteProp.WebsCount);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSOM C# code for your reference.

```
public static int subSiteCount = 0;
public static int groupCount = 0;
public static int listCount = 0;

static void  Main(string[] args)
{
    string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
    string userName = "test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
    string password = "xxx";

    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
    GetAllSubWebs(siteUrl, userName, securePassword);
    Console.WriteLine("Sub Site Count:"+subSiteCount+" Group Count:"+groupCount+" List Count:"+listCount);
}
private static void GetAllSubWebs(string path, string userName, SecureString password)
{
    // ClienContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Online Site               
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(path))
    {
        // SharePoint Online Credentials    
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);

        // Get the SharePoint web  
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);

        // Execute the query to the server  
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // Loop through all the webs  
        foreach (Web subWeb in web.Webs)
        {
            // Check whether it is an app URL or not - If not then get into this block  
            if (subWeb.Url.Contains(path))
            {
                string newpath = subWeb.Url;

                GetAllSubWebs(newpath, userName, password);

                clientContext.Load(subWeb.SiteGroups);
                clientContext.Load(subWeb.Lists);                        
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                subSiteCount += 1;
                groupCount += subWeb.SiteGroups.Count;
                listCount += subWeb.Lists.Count;
                //Console.WriteLine("GroupCount:" + subWeb.SiteGroups.Count);
                //Console.WriteLine("ListCount:" + subWeb.Lists.Count);
                //Console.WriteLine(subWeb.Title + "-------" + subWeb.Url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using "website=> website.Webs, website=> website.Title" ?

Comment: Retrieve the web's title and sub webs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I executed this code and got number of subsites in the Site:)

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace GetAllSubsites
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName = "kailash@kailash.cf";
            string siteURL = "https://developer19.sharepoint.com/sites/codesite";
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "pAsSwOrD".ToCharArray())
                password.AppendChar(c);

            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
            {  
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Webs);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                int b = 0;
                foreach (Web subWeb in web.Webs)
                {
                    if (subWeb.Url.Contains(siteURL))
                        b += 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Total Number of Subsite is " + b);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```